# Cannot publish chrome extension to the world

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have the following issue when attempting to publish a chrome extension. After having paid the $5 developer licence fee, I have been able to publish my extension to testers. However now it appears there is no way to publish the extension to the world. According to the documentation:

> Publishing your app is easy—just click the "Publish" link next to your
>   app in the dashboard. Or in the dashboard's edit page for your app,
>   click the Publish button.
>
> **Note**: To publish to the world after publishing to test accounts, you first need to **unpublish** the app.

My extension is currently published to test accounts:

[image]

When I click Unpublish (and after dismissing the warning message) I get this:

[image]

When I click Publish, I get this message:

[image]

After clicking yes, however, you can see the status is still "Published to Testers":

[image]

and also, you can see I still have 0 extensions published:

[image]

I notice also that there is no "Publish" button in the edit page for my extension as it says there should be in the documentation.

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me I'm being stupid!

Comment: Looks like you followed all the right steps. You might want to contact Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, clicking on "Publish" from the main dashboard will publish the extension with the previous settings (testers-only: yes/no).

Follow these steps to publish an item after having published it to testers:

1. Unpublish the item.
2. Click on the "Edit" link (`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/.....`)
3. Scroll down to the bottom.
4. Click on "Publish changes" (the right-most button).

Now, your item will be publicly visible instead of testers-only (within a couple of minutes).